# Merging multiple Splunk results

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I need to write a Splunk query to get the status when given pid, last status should be printed,wrote individual queries to fetch the status but dnt know how to merge the queries.referred few docs but couldn't find a way.

```
"##payto"|rex field=msg "personid :(?<pid>[^,]+)" |rex field=msg ",(?<status>[^,\]]+) 
//if this status is SUCCESS then i need to check for status of next step else i need to print this status

 "Event :start"|rex field=msg "personid :(?<pid>[^,]+)"|rex field=msg " Status :(?<status>[^,]+)"
//if response is 200 then need to go to next step else print this status
```

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Need to check 3 conditions, any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 | rex field=msg "personid :(?<pid>[^,]+)" 
    | rex field=msg ",(?<status>[^,\]]+)
    | join type=left pid
        [search  "Event :start"
        | rex field=msg "personid :(?<pid>[^,]+)"
        | rex field=msg " Status :(?<status_2nd>[^,]+)"
        | table pid, status_2nd
        ]
    | eval status=if(status=200,status_2nd,status)
    | table pid,status
```

**P.S.** I cannot remember the exact syntax of function `if` . :(

Comment: above query is not working, throwing error in the search block of query,

Comment: Hmm, I just copied what you wrote in the problem description. If executing it, please correct it to a executable query. For example, `[search index=blabla | rex ...]`